# How to fetch data from array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

i have below mongoDB collection data. i am trying to fetch data using typesOfExicution, companyName and projectName.
i have wrote the below query for finding

```
db.getCollection('SETTINGS').find({'companyName':'VV', 'typesOfExicution' : 'validation', 'automation.projectName' : 'hdh'})
```

if i don't use `automation.projectName` i am able to find the data. but if i use this then it is returning 0 records.

so what is the exact query to find data from an Array.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abce315cabca22270eead6a"),
    "typesOfExicution" : "validation",
    "modesOfExicution" : "auto",
    "automation[0][projectName]" : "Second",
    "automation[0][modules][]" : "Second module",
    "automation[0][assets][]" : "Second assets",
    "companyName" : "VV"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abce31ccabca22270eead6b"),
    "typesOfExicution" : "validation",
    "modesOfExicution" : "auto",
    "automation[0][projectName]" : "Second",
    "automation[0][modules][]" : "Second module",
    "automation[0][assets][]" : "Second assets",
    "companyName" : "VV"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5abce321cabca22270eead6c"),
    "typesOfExicution" : "validation",
    "modesOfExicution" : "auto",
    "automation[0][projectName]" : "hdh",
    "automation[0][modules][]" : "ds",
    "automation[0][assets][]" : "djv",
    "companyName" : "VV"
}
```

Comment: To search  from an Array you would do the same as it was another field. Like: "automation.projectName: "Second", "automation.modules": "Second Module". If you need multiple conditions from the same Array, use $elemMatch

Comment: @Sangram Badi, check the answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very sure of how your stored document is structured. I believe it looks something like:

```
   {
      "typesOfExicution": string,
      "modesOfExicution": string,
      "automation": [{ projectName: string, modules: string, assets: string }]
      "companyName" : string
   }
```

If you want to perform a query over `projectName`, which belongs to objects composing the array `automation`, you need to use the `$elemMatch` operator:

```
   db.getCollection('SETTINGS').find({'companyName':'VV', 'typesOfExicution' : 'validation', 'automation' : { $elemMatch: { 'projectName': 'myProject' } }  })
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you should store arrays in MongoDB. You should store array elements as embedded documents. As @Alexis mentioned here, there's no clarity on what exactly is your DB collection structure, so I hope this is what expected as per your given inputs:

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5abce315cabca22270eead6a"),
"typesOfExicution" : "validation",
"modesOfExicution" : "auto",
"automation" : [ 
    {
        "projectName" : "Second",
        "modules" : [ 
            "Second module"
        ],
        "assets" : [ 
            "Second assets"
        ]
    }
],
"companyName" : "VV"
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5abce31ccabca22270eead6b"),
"typesOfExicution" : "validation",
"modesOfExicution" : "auto",
"automation" : [ 
    {
        "projectName" : "Second",
        "modules" : [ 
            "Second module"
        ],
        "assets" : [ 
            "Second assets"
        ]
    }
],
"companyName" : "VV"
}

/* 3 */
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5abce321cabca22270eead6c"),
"typesOfExicution" : "validation",
"modesOfExicution" : "auto",
"automation" : [ 
    {
        "projectName" : "hdh",
        "modules" : [ 
            "ds"
        ],
        "assets" : [ 
            "djv"
        ]
    }
],
"companyName" : "VV"
}
```

Once you have the data as per mentioned above, use `automation.projectName` and you should get results like this:

[image]